# woocommerce remove_action not working, cannot remove right sidebar

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar, wordpress-hook

I am using woocommerce plugin and Wordpress. I need to remove sidebar only on one page (I have contact page where I don't want it to be displayed).
This is what I tried so far:

1. adding `remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );` to functions.php
2. adding `function woocommerce_remove_sidebar_shop() {
   if( is_page('Contact')){
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
   }
   }
   add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_remove_sidebar_shop' );`
   to functions.php
3. removing get_sidebar() from themes/sidebar.php file
4. removing  `add_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );` from template_hooks.php
   None of those worked and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a caching issue? Maybe try a hard refresh? Also, did you try removing your conditional to see if it works to make sure that's not the issue?

Comment: Yes, I tried without conditional, that is the first try. I also assumed it may be cashing, so I tried from another browse, also did not work.